# center fixed width divs in a variable parent div

Tags: css, html, center

I have a problem I can't solve.
i'm trying to auto center multiple 150x150px divs in a parent div that is 80% width (but it could also be 90% or 100%).
I have an isotope JQuery attached that works fine but when I enlarge my navigator window, the child divs do not move and furthermore, they do not center "live" (the menu above works fine).

Here is the html code :

```
<div class="portfolioContainer">
  <div id="marque" class="interieur">
    <p class="categorie"><a href="http://www.arper.it" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/logo_arper_140_Noir.jpg" width="100" height="33"></a><br>
    <span class="txt">ARPER</span><br>
    MOBILIER</p>
  </div>
  <div id="marque" class="interieur exterieur">
    <p class="categorie"><a href="http://www.b-line.it" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/logo_bline_140_Noir.jpg" width="140"></a><br>
    <span class="txt">B-LINE</span><br>
    MOBILIER</p>
  </div>
  <div id="marque" class="audio ipod">
    <p class="categorie"><a href="http://www.bowers-wilkins.fr" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/logo_BW_140_Noir.jpg" width="80" height="33"></a><br>
    <span class="txt">BOWERS &amp; WILKINS</span><br>
    AUDIO</p>
  </div>
  <div id="marque" class="audio">
    <p class="categorie"><a href="http://www.clearaudio.de" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/logo_clearaudio_140_Noir.jpg" width="80" height="74"></a><br>
    <span class="txt">CLEARAUDIO</span><br>
    PLATINES VINYLE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#container {
width:80%;
padding-top:50px;
position:relative;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
}

p {
width:150px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
bottom:20px;
text-align:center; /* centrage horizontal */
}

img {
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

#marque { 
position:relative;
width: 150px; 
height: 150px; 
margin:2px;
float:left;
border: solid 1px #333;
text-align:center;
}
```

The page can be found at this address to see the whole html/CSS code:
[www.pixsix.fr/marques.html](http://www.pixsix.fr/marques.html)

Comment: if your problem solved, accept answer by clicking on green tick

Answer (score 4):

replace `float: left` to `display: inline-block`

test it :

```
#marque { 
position:relative;
width: 150px; 
height: 150px; 
margin:2px;
display: inline-block;
border: solid 1px #333;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Maybe 1 comment here: This will not work in older browsers (e.g. IE7), if they do not know the inline-block